# paypal createOrder (javascript sdk)

Tags: paypal

```
createOrder: function (data, actions) {
        getOrderUid().then(res=>{
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [
                 {
                    amount: {
                        value: 100,
                        currency_code: 'USD'
                    },
                    reference_id: res.data.order.id
                }
              ]
            })
        })
```

An error：
Uncaught Error: Expected an order id to be passed

I need to process the business at the same time before creating it, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The `createOrder` callback function needs to itself return (pass back) the result or Promise of an order being created. You appear to have inserted a 10 ms setTimeout for some reason and are not passing back anything what is necessary.

> I need to process the business at the same time before creating it

What does this mean? Rephrase whatever you mean by this if it's important.

Comment: I changed the code, I want to get the orderId write inside the reference_id when createOrder is executed

Comment: If you need to do operations like that, or store anything in a database, you should use a server-side v2/checkout/orders integration with this approval flow https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: The client-side functions actions.order.create / actions.order.capture are only suitable for very simple sites and use cases, which it seems yours is not.